# Hide grid view on canvs using fabric.js

Tags: jquery, canvas, fabricjs

Here is the code exactly have to remove grid line on click button i am using canvas with fabric.js[here is link](http://cutting-edge.bluecoresys.com/cuttingEdge_old/public_html/CutEdege%20fabric%20js%20sanjay/?textarea=%20)

```
   $("#ungrid").click(function() {


                var a= fabric.GetLine();  
              alert(a);

        var width = canvas.width;
        var height = canvas.height;

        var j = 0;
        var line = null;
        var rect = [];
        var size = 20;

        console.log(width + ":" + height);

        for (var i = 0; i < Math.ceil(width / 20); ++i) {
            rect[0] = i * size;
            rect[1] = 0;

            rect[2] = i * size;
            rect[3] = height;

            line = null;
            line = new fabric.Line(rect, {
                stroke: '#999',
                opacity: 0.5
            });
```

Here is function canvas remove line
             canvas.remove(line);
            // canvas.clear(line);
                line.selectable = false;

```
      canvas.remove(line);
            line.sendToBack();

        }

        for (i = 0; i < Math.ceil(height / 20); ++i) {
            rect[0] = 0;
            rect[1] = i * size;

            rect[2] = width;
            rect[3] = i * size;

            line = null;
            line = new fabric.Line(rect, {
                stroke: '#999',
                opacity: 0.5
            });
            line.selectable = false;

            canvas.remove(line);
            line.sendToBack();

        }
        canvas.remove(line);
        canvas.renderAll(); 

              }) ;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code :

```
var canObject = new Array();
canObject = canvas.getObjects();
while(1){
    for(var tempObjNumber = 0;tempObjNumber<canObject.length;tempObjNumber++){
       if(canvas.item(tempObjNumber).type == 'line'){
            canvas.item(tempObjNumber).remove();
         canvas.renderAll();
        }
    }
    canvas.renderAll();
    canObject = canvas.getObjects();
    var lineStatus = false;
    for(var tempObjNumber = 0;tempObjNumber<canObject.length;tempObjNumber++){
        if(canvas.item(tempObjNumber).type == 'line'){
        lineStatus = true;
        }
    }
    if(lineStatus){
        canObject = canvas.getObjects();
        continue;
    }else{
        break;
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the total solution.
add and remove grid in canvas fabric.js for add grid in canvas
    create button grid in ht ml  and to remove grid create button ungrid in ht ml 
    id and class of the button will be same as name

```
     $("#grid").click(function() {
   var width = canvas.width;
var height = canvas.height;
var j = 0;
var line = null;
var rect = [];
var size = 20;
console.log(width + ":" + height);
 for (var i = 0; i < Math.ceil(width / 20); ++i) {
    rect[0] = i * size;
    rect[1] = 0;
    rect[2] = i * size;
    rect[3] = height;
    line = null;
    line = new fabric.Line(rect, {
        stroke: '#999',
        opacity: 0.5
    });
      line.selectable = false;
      canvas.add(line);
       line.sendToBack();
        }
for (i = 0; i < Math.ceil(height / 20); ++i) {
    rect[0] = 0;
    rect[1] = i * size;
    rect[2] = width;
    rect[3] = i * size;
    line = null;
    line = new fabric.Line(rect, {
        stroke: '#999',
        opacity: 0.5
    });
    line.selectable = false;
  canvas.add(line);
    line.sendToBack();
   }
   canvas.renderAll();
});
//************************Remove Grid***************
$("#ungrid").click(function () {
//alert("ungrid");
var canObject = new Array();
canObject = canvas.getObjects();
while(1){
    for(var tempObjNumber = 0;tempObjNumber<canObject.length;tempObjNumber++){
       if(canvas.item(tempObjNumber).type == 'line'){
            canvas.item(tempObjNumber).remove();
         canvas.renderAll();
        }
    }
    canvas.renderAll();
    canObject = canvas.getObjects();
    var lineStatus = false;
    for(var tempObjNumber = 0;tempObjNumber<canObject.length;tempObjNumber++){
        if(canvas.item(tempObjNumber).type == 'line'){
        lineStatus = true;
        }
    }
    if(lineStatus){
        canObject = canvas.getObjects();
        continue;
    }else{
        break;
    }       
}
});
```